# Hiding placeholder inside updatepanel from asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using an `updatepanel` inside a jQuery popup on an asp.net page. In this `updatepanel`, I have two placeholders. On one placeholder, I have a form with buttons. When I click the save button, record is saved in database. Now after record is saved. I want to hide this placeholder with form.

And show other placeholder which is thank you message. How can I do it ?

I am doing like this:

```
RegisterPH.Visible = false;
ThankYouPH.Visible = true;
ModalUpdatePanel.Update();
```

My html markup is like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ModalUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRegister" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="RegisterPH" runat="server">
      </asp:PlaceHolder>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ThankYouPH" runat="server" Visible="false">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="RegisterText2">
                  <asp:Literal ID="ThankYouContentLiteral" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Register, ThankYouContent %>" />
              </div>
          </div>
     </asp:PlaceHolder>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Do I need to use `updatepanel`'s `endrequest` function or register some script ? Please suggest.

Comment: Can't you just do something like `RegisterPH.visible = false ThankYouPH.visible = true` ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I did that as i show in above code, but it does nothing

Comment: Sorry didn't see it originally. This should've worked, strange. You don't have to call `ModalUpdatePanel.Update()` btw

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should work. Make sure you are putting a `<asp:ScriptManager />` control on your page (or RadScriptManager if you are using Telerik, ToolkitScriptManager if you are using Microsoft's AjaxToolkit, etc.)

**EDIT:**
Following is code that works correctly using `UpdatePanel` and the Bootstrap modal dialog you mentioned:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="bootstrap.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWeb.bootstrap" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder id="p1" runat="server">
                    <asp:Literal id="lit1" runat="server" Text="Placeholder 1" />
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                <asp:PlaceHolder id="p2" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <asp:Literal id="lit2" runat="server" Text="Placeholder 2" />
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Save" OnClick="btn_Click" />
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.p1.Visible = false;
    this.p2.Visible = true;
}
```

I would encourage you to create a test page in your app with just this markup to confirm that it works in your environment. Assuming it does, then I would take your problematic code and start pulling pieces out. Maybe put same plain text in the second `Placeholder` control instead of a couple of styled divs and a `Literal` that pulls its text from a resource file. Comment out your data update code so that all your Save button is doing is toggling visibility on the two `Placeholder` controls. If you still can't get it to work after stripping your page down to the bare minimum, then post more of your code and I'll take another look.

Comment: I am using bootstrap modal popup and with above code it is not updating contents after data is saved. I didn't find any link from google as well. please suggest any solution.